# Loop to fill an String array for use in listview (not fill from loop)

Tags: java, android

How to use "CurrlstArr" is not able to show the value . I dont know whats the problem using for loop string array.

```
    mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.listView100 );


     SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MY_FAVOURITES", MODE_PRIVATE); 
String    test_string = prefs.getString("name", "");

  persons = test_string.split("DDDDDDDDDD");

 int  t = persons.length;

  if(t<0)

  {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"xtronlabs", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
  else

  {
      for (int i = 0; i < persons.length; i++)
      {
      String currlst = persons[i];
    currlstArr = currlst.split("LLLLLLLLLL");  

    caption = currlstArr[0];

     vlink = currlstArr[1];


      }


    mainListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,currlstArr ));

  }
```

How to use String value on listview i dnt know what my error.

Comment: Fix that horrible formatting.

Comment: I was not able to set the received values to listview ?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the part where you declare "currlstArr". You are setting the value of currlstArr inside the foreach, so, if t< 0 you have nothing set, otherwise, you have the value of .split. Your use of setAdapter itself looks fine. Try

```
currlstArr = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
        "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
        "Linux", "OS/2", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X", "Linux",
        "OS/2", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X", "Linux", "OS/2",
        "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile" };
```

Comment: mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.listView100 );


   SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MY_FAVOURITES", MODE_PRIVATE); 
 String    test_string = prefs.getString("name", "");persons = test_string.split("DDDDDDDDDD");
  int  t = persons.length;
   String s=Integer.toString(t);
     for (int i = 0; i < persons.length; i++)
    {
    String currlst = persons[i];
      currlstArr = currlst.split("LLLLLLLLLL");  
     }

Comment: I was not able to set the received values to listview